# How to dynamically build compile classpath in a Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm a professional services consultant for a software product company.  Our product provides a Java API so field customizations can be built.  These extensions are dependent upon up to 50 individual JAR files - some proprietary to our product, others are open source.

I don't want to hard code the dependencies in the POM for several reasons - mostly because each new release will depend on slighty different versions of the open source artifacts.  When a new product is released, I simply want to point to the new installation folder and rebuild the extensions.

So, I'm trying to create a Maven plugin that takes a reference to the installation folder, recurses through the folders, and automatically adds all *.jar files to the compile-time classpath.

I tried this:

```
Map<?, ?> context = getPluginContext();
MavenProject maven = (MavenProject) context.get("project");
List<String> classpath = maven.getCompileClasspathElements();

// start adding additional elements to the classpath
```

That snippet executes during the initialize phase, but the classpath reverts by the time compiling starts and the compile fails.  Am I even going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like the way to go.

Rather try to analyze how the installation folder is assembled. Try to create this installation folder with Maven, too, and provide a POM with all used dependencies (BOM - Bill of Materials).

Then use this BOM-POM as dependency (scope=provided) in your extensions.